# Using IPython from the Python shell like `code.interact()`

Tags: python, shell, ipython

Is it possible to use the IPython shell from an existing Python shell, as a shell-inside-a-shell, similarly to the built-in `code.interact()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [recommended way](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython) of embedding IPython works fine:

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7 [...]
>>> from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
>>> ipshell = IPShellEmbed()
>>> ipshell()

In [1]:
```

Answer (score 23):

In **IPython 0.11** the API has been overhauled and the shell is even easier to invoke:

```
import IPython

IPython.embed()
```

Answer (score 1):

Django `manage.py shell` invoke a IPython shell when possible, and it's implemented like this:

```
import IPython

shell = IPython.Shell.IPShell()
shell.mainloop()
```