# How can I start the python console within a program (for easy debugging)?

Tags: python, console, debugging, interpreter

After years of research programming in Matlab, I miss the way I could pause a program mid-execution and inspect the variables, do plotting, save/modify data, etc. via the interactive console, and then resume execution.

Is there a way to do the same thing in python?

For example:

---

```
   # ... python code ...
   RunInterpreter
   # Interactive console is displayed, so user can inspect local/global variables
   # User types CTRL-D to exit, and script then continues to run
   # ... more python code ...
```

---

This would make debugging a lot easier. Suggestions much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The excellent solution I found was to use the 'code' module. I can now call 'DebugKeyboard()' from anywhere in my code and the interpreter prompt will pop-up, allowing me to examine variables and run code. CTRL-D will continue the program.

```
import code
import sys    

def DebugKeyboard(banner="Debugger started (CTRL-D to quit)"):

    # use exception trick to pick up the current frame
    try:
        raise None
    except:
        frame = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back

    # evaluate commands in current namespace
    namespace = frame.f_globals.copy()
    namespace.update(frame.f_locals)

    print "START DEBUG"
    code.interact(banner=banner, local=namespace)
    print "END DEBUG"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `pdb` library.

I have this line bound to `<F8>` in Vim:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

That will drop you into a `pdb` console.

The `pdb` console isn't *quite* the same as the standard Python console… But it will do most of the same stuff. Also, in my `~/.pdbrc`, I've got:

```
alias i from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed as IPSh; IPSh(argv='')()
```

So that I can get into a "real" iPython shell from `pdb` with the `i` command:

```
(pdb) i
...
In [1]:
```

Comment: Hey, nice iPython! Gotta give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

The [`code`](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module contains classes for bringing up a REPL.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about it. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Python debugger](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html). In short, you can insert

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

at any point in your program that you want to debug. (Note that you should remove these in release versions!)

Answer (score 1):

[pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) is what you're looking for - just put a call to `pdb.set_trace()` wherever you want to drop into an debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better, simpler solution, works in Python 3.8
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1396386/4566456

Even more powerful if IPython is installed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152484/4566456